# Checking internet conection on Android Nougat without deprecated methods

Tags: android, internet-connection

According to the documentation I cannot make own `ConnectionChangeReceiver` with

```
<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
```

because `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` is deprecated.

And using the `JobExecutor` is a bad idea because it checks the internet connection not less than once every 15 minutes... Useless tool.

So, how can I check the internet connection in background (service or some receiver) without deprecated methods on all versions of OS Android?

Comment: Use JobService for check internet connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app can still receive notifications, on Nougat, for Connectivity change if you explicitly use a `BroadcastReceiver` and request notifications.

Quoting from the documentation:

> Apps targeting Android 7.0 (API level 24) and higher do not receive CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcasts if they declare their broadcast receiver in the manifest. Apps will still receive CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcasts if they register their BroadcastReceiver with Context.registerReceiver() and that context is still valid.

To make it work across different android versions, you can use declare the permission in the manifest, as we usually do and additionally, in your activity use the following code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    registerReceiver(mNetworkReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
}
```